# Problem in saving the many to many entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Here's my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_pedido")
public class ProdutoPedido {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "produto_id")
    private Produto produto;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "pedido_id")
    private Pedido pedido;

    private int quantidade;

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

The repository:

```
public interface ProdutoPedidoRepository extends CrudRepository<ProdutoPedido, Long> {

}
```

And the controller's method to save:

```
@PostMapping("/itensdevendas")
    public ProdutoPedido salvarProdutoPedido(@RequestBody ProdutoPedido produtoPedido) {
        return produtoPedidoRepository.save(produtoPedido);
    }
```

the Postman's call:

```
{
    "quantidade":33,
    "pedido_id":1,
    "produto_id":4
}
```

However only the `quantidade` and `id` attributes are fullfilled. 
What's wrong for the attributes `pedido_id` and `produto_id` are not being saved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I owe you a beer. It worked with some modifications. I list them here:

The id attribute for ProdutoPedidoDTO was not necessary.

Furthemore, I had to change the return type of the method "salvar" from ProdutoPedidoDTO to just ProdutoPedido.

```
@PostMapping("/itensdevendas")
    public ProdutoPedido salvarProdutoPedido(@RequestBody ProdutoPedidoDTO produtoPedidoDTO) {

        ProdutoPedido prodPedido = new ProdutoPedido();
        // add values

        System.out.println("Primeiro: " + produtoPedidoDTO.getProduto());

        // add Produto obj to ProdutoPedido
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        //produto.setId(produtoPedidoDTO.getProduto());
        produto = produtoRepository.findById(produtoPedidoDTO.getProduto()).get();
        prodPedido.setProduto(produto);

        System.out.println("Segundo: " + produtoPedidoDTO.getPedido());

        // do same for Pedido 
        Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
        // pedido.setId(produtoPedidoDTO.getPedido());
        pedido = pedidoRepository.findById(produtoPedidoDTO.getPedido()).get();
        prodPedido.setPedido(pedido);

        prodPedido.setQuantidade(produtoPedidoDTO.getQuantidade());

        return produtoPedidoRepository.save(prodPedido);
    }
```

Lastly, here's how the Post call look like:

```
{
    "quantidade":66,
    "pedido":1,
    "produto":3
}
```

Thank you for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Entity `ProdutoPedido`  has `Produto`  Object.

If you pass 1 for produto it wont get mapped and value will remain null.

**Note:** I assume 1 and 4 data for Produto and Pedido already exist.

You can try 2 approach

**First:**

Change your JSON from UI to something like this, assuming `Produto` and `Pedido` object has "id" field.

Hopefully it will get converted to Produto and Pedido object.

Confirm it by printing it in controller method.

```
{
    "quantidade":33,
    "pedido_id": { "id" : 1 },
    "produto_id": { "id" : 4 }
}
```

**Second:**

You need to add a DTO like this and use same for UI mapping.

```
ProdutoPedidoDTO {

    private Long id;
    private int produto;
    private int pedido;
    private int quantidade;

}


@PostMapping("/itensdevendas")
public ProdutoPedidoDTO salvarProdutoPedido(@RequestBody ProdutoPedidoDTO produtoPedido) {

    ProdutoPedido prodPedido = new ProdutoPedido();
    // add values

    // add Produto obj to ProdutoPedido
    Produto produto = new Produto();
    produto.setId(produtoPedido.getProduto()):
    prodPedido.setProduto(produto);

    // do same for Pedido 

    return produtoPedidoRepository.save(prodPedido);
}
```

Comment: So basically what you're asking me here is this: change produtoPedidoRepository to save a "produto" instance rather than a "produtoPedido" instance ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, last line will be prodPedido only.  Repository will remind same in 2nd approach. Just adding dto. Object which will have ids as int for Produto. Or you can try first approach and see if it works.  Changes are only on json side.

Comment: And according to 2nd approach how is it supposed to be the JSON of the call ?

Comment: JSON will remain the same as you added in question.